# Ngrx Component Store: Can I call another effect inside a effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm currently implementing a feature that "*open a snackbar*"(effect),if close snackbar with action then "*open a dialog*"(effect) and finally make an *API call*(effect) after the dialog close.

I want to implement this feature in Component Store,

```
openDialog = this.effect((trigger$) => 
    trigger$.pipe( 
    exhuastMap(() => this.dialog.open(comp).afterClosed().pipe(
    tap((result) => this.callApi(result))))))

snackBar = this.effect((trigger$)=>
   trigger$.pipe(
   exhuastMap(()=> this.snackBar.open("test","OK").onAction().pipe(
   tap(() => this.openDialog())))))
```

I noticed that the source implementation of effect() will return a subscription, so is calling another effect inside an effect OK or not?
If not, I will need to create additional states to trigger above effects or convert some of them into normal function in the service.

Comment: Can you please add the code which shows what is `this.effect`? I'm bit confused what and where are you trying to achieve. Is this a code from some component or dedicated effects.ts file?

Comment: @dallows this.effect is from Ngrx Component Store library https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/effect

Comment: I know, but did you inject it directly into the component? This looks like a serious anti-pattern approach. You never call effect, you dispatch and action and NgRx handles side effects on that action.

Comment: No, I create a service that extends the componentStore class, I follow the guide, there's no actions called in the guide, but calling the effects directly.

Comment: I think you need to provide more of your code in order to others to be able to be helpful.
That being said: You cannot 'call' effects as you seem to understand it, since they are Observables. They are wrapped by store mechanics which actually subscribe to a provided effect.

But you could use just simple effects to achieve what you want:
First, you will need a store attribute "isDialogOpen" and you can set that attribute to true in the "closeSnackbarAction" in the reducer. Then you have an *ngIf around your dialog component which listens to the isDialogOpen attribute via a selector.

Comment: I think I can create a selector for triggering the openDialog effect. or just create a normal function that open the dialog and return an observable. Actually, I'm a bit confused about Rxjs, is it ok that subscribe an observable within a tap operator? Based on the source code of ComponentStore.effect() , 'This effect is subscribed to for the life of the @Component' and returns 'A function that, when called, will trigger the origin Observable.' Does this mean it will create nesting subscribe, if I call an effect inside another effect?

Comment: This question is about the Component Store, where effects are used differently from the "usual" Ngrx store. I think most of the comments above were thinking about effects in the Ngrx store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/a9e7fb177c4750ac5c8a39ea3898454669cde847/modules/component-store/src/component-store.ts#L268-L311), there should be no problem with calling one effect from another. The `effect` function doesn't do that much. It will just push the values you call the effect with to a `Subject` (your `trigger$`), so it shouldn't matter where you call it from.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a callback function and passing to **openDialog effect** from **snackBar effect** , like this:

```
readonly openDialog = this.effect<{
        whenApiDone: () => void
    }>((arg$) => {
       return arg$.pipe(
           tap((arg) => {
               const isDone = ...;
               if(isDone){
                   arg.whenApiDone();
               }
           })
       )
    };
            


    readonly snackBar = this.effect<{
        whenApiDone: () => void
    }>((arg$) => {
        return arg$.pipe(
                // doSomeThing...
                tap(() => this.openDialog(arg))
            )
    }
```